# How to avoid specifying the size of included graphic when the file has no extension?

Tags: graphics, xetex

I'm rendering the following code with xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[debugshow]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
%% This gives ! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in lowres (no size specifed).
\includegraphics[type=png]{lowres}
%% This works fine without specified size.
\includegraphics{highres.png}
\end{document}
```

I've got the files 'lowres' and 'highres.png' in my current directory:

```
$ file lowres 
lowres: PNG image data, 348 x 350, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced
$ file highres.png 
highres.png: PNG image data, 348 x 350, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

The obvious difference between these files is the lack of extension for 'lowres', so that's why I specify the type in the 'includegraphics'.

The problem is, it looks like it is mandatory to specify the size when the file hasn't got any extension (although we give the type as a parameter).

This behaviour doesn't make sense to me, is there a way to get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify an extension as part of the filename with `\includegraphics` a predefined set of extension is used to search for a suitable file. If you use only `lowres` then it looks for the files `lowres.png`, `lowres.jpg` and `lowres.pdf` (not necessary in this order) and uses the first one which is found. It does not look for a `lowres` file without any extension. 
The `type` option is rather deprecated, IIRC, and might not do what you expect from it.

The best thing would be to simply rename the file in question to have the correct file extension. You could also define an empty extension as part of the default extension list and remove the `type` option.

The following works for me. Apparently XeTeX is smart enough to figure out the real type without an extension, which actually isn't very difficult.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[debugshow]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,}% Note the trailing ',' which defines an empty extension
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{lowres}
\includegraphics{highres.png}
\end{document}
```